# Что нам даёт добавление стилей псевдоклассу :focus для кнопок и ссылок при вёрстке для мобильные устройства?

Tags: css

Имеет ли смысл добавлять стили псевдоклассу `:focus` для кнопок и ссылок при верстке под мобильные устройства? Ведь на мобильных устройствах событие `:focus` (как и `:hover`), если оно и существует, то непонятно когда и главное зачем оно срабатывает.

Предвижу возражение: "Так десктопных устройствах стили для этого состояния же нужны - чтобы была реакция на перебор кнопок клавишей tab. А поскольку в адаптивном дизайне мы заранее не знаем, с какого устройства осуществляет управление пользователь, то применять стили для `:focus` и `:hover` всё равно нужно!". Так вот, в современном CSS есть медиа-запрос типа `@media (hover: hover)`, с помощью которого можно применить стили, в частности - для псевдоклассов `:focus` и `:hover` только на тех устройствах, где событие `:hover` существует осмыслено (то есть в основном на десктопных устройствах). Если ли какая-нибудь рациональная причина, по которой я не должен так делать?

Comment: `:focus` это псевдо-класс, а не псевдо-элемент. Никто не мешает подключить к мобильнику/планшету клавиатуру и «ходить по кнопкам табом».

Comment: Более того, к нему и мышку можно подключить и `:hover` станет актуален

Comment: В полной мере `:focus` для Вас раскроется, когда столкнётесь с [Accessibility](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:hover` действительно не работает так как нет курсора. Чисто технически на мобилке курсор можно включить и даже мышку подключить, но это больше для "поиграться".

А вот псевдокласс `:focus` прекрасно работает на мобильных устройствах. Более того, его часто используют для создания анимаций как замену `:hover`. Также на некоторых видеохостингах псевдокласс `:focus` используется для проигрывания превю видео.

Ниже пример увеличения картинки при фокусе. Обратите внимание, что к картинкам я добавил атрибут tabindex так как картинки по умолчанию нельзя брать в фокус.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div img {
  display: block;
  transition: 1s;
}

div img:focus {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100x100/" alt="" tabindex="1"></div>
<div><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100x100/" alt="" tabindex="2"></div>
<div><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100x100/" alt="" tabindex="3"></div>
```